# How to create and return string from function?

Tags: c++, string, function

Would like to generate a string from a function, in order to format some data, so the function should return a string.

Tried to do the "obvious", shown below, but this prints garbage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char * hello_world()
{
    char res[13];
    memcpy(res, "Hello world\n", 13);
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf(hello_world());
    return 0;
}
```

I think this is because the memory on the stack used for the `res` variable, defined in the function, is overwritten before the value can be written, maybe when the `printf` call uses the stack.

If I move `char res[13];` outside the function, thus makes it global, then it works.

So is the answer to have a global char buffer (string) that can be used for the result?

Maybe doing something like:

```
char * hello_world(char * res)
{
    memcpy(res, "Hello world\n", 13);  // 11 characters + newline + 0 for string termination
    return res;
}

char res[13];

int main(void)
{
    printf(hello_world(res));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `std::string`?

Comment: Or you can add `using namespace std`. It is the C++ Standard Library which is a collection of classes and functions. The built in C++ library routines are kept in the standard namespace. That includes stuff like cout, cin, string, vector, map, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are programming [c](/questions/tagged/c). That's not bad, but your question is about [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so this is the solution for the question you asked:

```
std::string hello_world()
{
    std::string temp;

    // todo: do whatever string operations you want here
    temp = "Hello World";

    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    std::string result = hello_world();

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't bother with that early-20th century stuff. By the end of the previous century we already had `std::string`, and that's straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string hello_world()
{
    return "Hello world\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << hello_world();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; accepted the other answer, since it is closer to the actual application.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution would be to use `std::string`. However, if you must use an array, then it is best to allocate it in the calling function (in this case, `main()`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void hello_world(char * s)
{
    memcpy(s, "Hello world\n", 13);
}

int main(void)
{
    char mys[13];
    hello_world(mys);
    std::cout<<mys;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still, if you want to write a pure C code, will can do something like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *HelloWorld(char *s, int size)
{
        sprintf(s, "Hello world!\n");
        return s;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char s[100];

        printf(HelloWorld(s, 100));

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the memset for? It doesn't matter. Also, sprintf will cause a buffer overflow if size is too small.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it there for no reason. Let me edit it.